# Uppercase the second letter of each word in Python

Tags: python

Trying to solve a simple problem that seems to have a difficult answer. The problem is uppercase the second letter of each word in Python. I thought I had the code right, but it seems that its returning only the last word in the split.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def capitalize_n(s, n):
    result = ""
    for word in s.split():
        result = word[:n].lower() + word[n:].capitalize()
    return result
    
capitalize_n('hello world', 1)
```

output

```
wOrld
```

Comment: On each iteration, you update your **result** variable, etheir use += to append to result or try out Jonathan1609 solution

Comment: you overwrite result in the loop. `result = result + word[:n].lower() + word[n:].capitalize()`

Comment: Every time through the `for` loop your code is replacing the previous value of `result` with a new one, so it only keeps the last value. Store all of the reformatted words in a list and reassemble them into a string with `" ".join()` before returning the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does that do what you wanted?

```py
def capitalize_n(s, n):
    return " ".join(word[:n] + word[n:].capitalize() for word in s.split())


print(capitalize_n('hello world', 1))
```

The result is `hEllo wOrld`.

What you did wrong that is in each iteration you re-assigned to the variable `result` using the `=` operator instead of adding to that using the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Do this. You are always assigning But you should concatenate with previous also create a space.

```
def capitalize_n(s, n):
    result = ""
    for word in s.split():
        result += word[:n].lower() + word[n:].capitalize() + " "
    return result
    
capitalize_n('hello world', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

to modify your code, add += instead of =  ,
then fix for space

```
def capitalize_n(s, n):
    result = ""
    for word in s.split():
        result += word[:n].lower() + word[n:].capitalize() + ' '
    return result
    
capitalize_n('hello world', 1).strip()
```

output:

```
'hEllo wOrld'
```